# How to Upload Image to server

Tags: image

I try to send the image to the server via API. I was use

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Image String);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream); 
        byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
        String imageStr =  Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr,Base64.DEFAULT);
```

I used above code But I was got string not readable error from API. 
Into IOS APP image is uploading into the same API.

Please, Guys, Help me 
Thanks in Advance